# How do I create a jinja2 extension that registers a filter

Tags: python, jinja2

I'd like to create a `jinja2` extension that defines and registers a new filter.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
from jinja2.ext import Extension

def visible_only(value):
    return [v for v in value if not getattr(v, "visible", False)]

class MyExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, environment):
        environment.filters["visible_only"] = visible_only
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Flask with Jinja2, you can also use a decorator:

```
@app.template_filter('visible_only')
def visible_only(value):
    return [v for v in value if not getattr(v, "visible", False)]
```